# Filtering arguments in windows batch file

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file

Is it possible to filter list of arguments in windows batch file?

Assuming it is called like:

```
file.cmd arg1 --unwanted arg3
```

It should call some other executable (hardcoded) without the argument string `--unwanted`:

```
some.exe arg1 arg3
```

I only know the name of the argument, it can be passed as any argument in the list. It may not exist on argument list, and the all arguments should be passed unmodified. Number of arguments may vary.

More examples (what's called -> what should be called in result)

```
file.cmd arg1 arg2 -> some.exe arg1 arg2
file.cmd --unwanted -> some.exe
file.cmd --unwanted arg2 -> some.exe arg2
file.cmd arg1 --unwanted -> some.exe arg1
```

Moving from unix shell scripting windows batch files are black magic to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

if "%1"=="SOTEST" (
    REM tests...
    call file.cmd arg1 --unwanted arg3
    call file.cmd arg1 arg2
    call file.cmd --unwanted
    call file.cmd --unwanted arg2
    call file.cmd arg1 --unwanted
    goto :EOF
)

set params=
:nextparam
if "%~1"=="--unwanted" (shift&goto nextparam)
if not "%~1"=="" (set "params=%params%%1 "&shift&goto nextparam)

echo.%*^>^>%params%
```

This prints:

```
arg1 --unwanted arg3>>arg1 arg3
arg1 arg2>>arg1 arg2
--unwanted>>
--unwanted arg2>>arg2
arg1 --unwanted>>arg1
```

---

**Edit:**

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

if "%~1"=="SOTEST" (
    REM tests...
    call file.cmd arg1=foo --unwanted arg3=bar
    call file.cmd arg1 arg2
    call file.cmd --unwanted
    call file.cmd --unwanted arg2
    call file.cmd arg1 --unwanted
    call file.cmd "arg1" --unwanted "arg3"
    call file.cmd "arg1=foo" --unwanted arg3="bar"
    goto :EOF
)

set var=0
set params=
:nextparam
set /A var=%var% + 1
for /F "tokens=%var% delims= " %%A in ("%*") do (
    if not "%%~A"=="--unwanted" set "params=%params%%%A "
    goto nextparam
)

echo.%*^>^>%params%
```

prints

```
arg1=foo --unwanted arg3=bar>>arg1=foo arg3=bar
arg1 arg2>>arg1 arg2
--unwanted>>
--unwanted arg2>>arg2
arg1 --unwanted>>arg1
"arg1" --unwanted "arg3">>"arg1" "arg3"
"arg1=foo" --unwanted arg3="bar">>"arg1 foo" arg3="bar"
```

meaning "arg1=foo" is broken, you can switch the for loop to `for /F "tokens=%var% delims= " %%A in ('echo.%*') do (` to get it working, but that breaks arg1=foo and arg3="bar"

This is a known problem with batch files, once you start messing with strings things are going to get screwed up in some configuration since there is always some character that is going to mess things up (%,!,",^,&,|,<,>,space etc)

Comment: @Anders: Which means that you want *silk* to work out that the basic idea is to store all the params one by one into a variable skipping over the unwanted one and then use the variable to pass the filtered parameter list to the app. :)

Comment: @Andriy understanding is not a problem, writing it without batch knowledege is a problem

Comment: @Anders almost there, it is stripping = from parameters like "--pretty=format:%H" :(

Comment: @silk: It is not my code that does the stripping, cmd.exe is doing that

Comment: @silk: Anders is right. Putting params with '=' in double quotes can fix the issue, if that suits you.

Comment: I will have to try some other approach then. The problem is I need to wrap some executable which is called by an application and strip one parameter. I wanted to do that without modifying the application, but it seems not worth the trouble with such batch files behavior.
Anyhow - thanks for the answer.